# Project: Blackjack with Python using Pygame. How do I implement the result using pygame

Tags: python

I am trying to code Blackjack using pygame. I am having difficulties trying to implement the results of the game.
eg.:

```
def results(sum_player, sum_dealer)
    if sum_player == 21:
        print("Blackjack! Player has" + str(sum_player) + "while dealer has:" + str(sum_dealer))
        run = False)
```

I want a button or some kind of output in pygame that shows who won the game. Then I need the game to end or reset so i can play again.

Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

> I want a button or some kind of output in pygame that shows who won the game. Then I need the game to end or reset so i can play again.

In order to display text on the screen in pygame, we will need to do a couple of things:

- First, we need to create a font for the text. In order to do that, we can use the `pygame.font.SysFont` function. You must add `pygame.init()` after `import pygame` to use this function. For information on how to use this function, check out [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont). 
  Example:
  `my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)`
- Next, we will render the text and save it to a variable.
  Example:
  `label = my_font.render("my text", True, (0, 0, 0))` --> (0, 0, 0) is black
- Lastly, we will need to display the text on the screen using the `window.blit` function.
  Example: `window.blit(label, (50, 100))`

Pygame doesn't include a prebuilt function for creating buttons, so we'll have to create one ourselves. In order to do that, I created a `Button` class that can display buttons. By using a class, we can use multiple buttons in the game without repeating code.

## The `Button` Class:

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, surface, text, bg, fg, x, y, width, height):
        self.surface = surface # the window
        self.bg = bg # the color of the button
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height) # creating a rectangle for the button
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", height//2, "bold") # creating the font for the button text
        self.label = font.render(text, True, fg) # rendering the text (fg = color of button text)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.bg, self.rect) # displaying the button rectangle
        self.surface.blit(self.label, (self.x + self.width*0.25,
                                       self.y + self.height*0.25)) # displaying the button text
```

To create a new button, just do the following:
`button = Button(window, "play", (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), 100, 200, 300, 80)`

### The parameters that it takes:

- **surface** --> the window of your game
- **text** --> the button text. For example: "Play"
- **bg** --> the background color of the button
- **fg** --> the color of the button text
- **x** --> the x position of the button
- **y** --> the y position of the button
- **width** --> the width of the button
- **height** --> the height of the button

The class also includes a function called `draw`, which is responsible for displaying the button.

## Combining Everything:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
# colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


class Button:
    def __init__(self, surface, text, bg, fg, x, y, width, height):
        self.surface = surface # the window
        self.bg = bg # the color of the button
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height) # creating a rectangle for the button
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", height//2, "bold") # creating the font for the button text
        self.label = font.render(text, True, fg) # rendering the text (fg = color of button text)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.bg, self.rect) # displaying the button rectangle
        self.surface.blit(self.label, (self.x + self.width*0.25,
                                       self.y + self.height*0.25)) # displaying the button text


def game():
    # your game code


def results():
    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50, "bold") # creating the font for the text
    label = my_font.render("Player 1 has won!", True, WHITE) # rendering the text in white
    reset_button = Button(window, "RESET", BLUE, WHITE, 100, 200, 300, 80) # creating a blue "reset" button

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # checking if the mouse is down
                if reset_button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos): # checking if the mouse clicked the reset button
                    game() # resetting the game

        window.fill(BLACK) # sets the window color to black
        window.blit(label, (50, 100)) # displaying the text on the screen
        reset_button.draw() # showing the button on the screen

        pygame.display.update() # updating the display

    pygame.quit()


results()
```

I added comments to the code that explain certain lines.